# enums doesn't properly translate in swagger (coming as string instead of enum)

Tags: spring, enums, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc

Failed to convert the value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.x.x.Recordtype'

Also, RecordType enum is a decompiled file, so can't make any changes to that.

in swagger-ui, recordTypes comes as a dropdown list.
dropdown list items

- RecordType.BILL(recordType=BILL, key=ABC#)
- RecordType.LAW(recordType=LAW, key=XYZ#)

Using

- Springdoc v2 for swagger-UI (https://springdoc.org/v2/)
- Spring Boot 3
- Spring Framework 6

```
//RecordType.class

import lombok.Generated;

public enum RecordType {
    BILL("BILL", "ABC#"),
    LAW("LAW", "XYZ#");
    
    private String recordType;
    private String key;
    
    @Generated
    public String getRecordType() {return this.recordType; }
    
    @Generated
    public string getKey() { return this.key; }
    
    @Generated
    private RecordType(final String recordtype, final String key) {
        this.recordType = recordType;
        this.key = key;
    }
    
    @Generated
    public String toString() {
        String alpha = this.name();
        return "RecordType:"+alpha+"(recordType="+this.getRecordtype+", key="+this.getKey()+")";
    }
}
```

DataController code

```
//DataController.java

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@Restcontroller
@RequestMapping("/api/internal")
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private IShopData shopData;
    
    @GetMapping("/entity/number")
    public <T>ResponseEntity<T> getResponseByRecordType(@RequestParam(name="recordType") RecordType recordType, @Requestparam(name = "data", required = false) boolean data) throws Exception{
        T response = shopData.getNumber(recordType, data );
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
    }
}
```

In  @GetMapping("/entity/number")
public ResponseEntity getResponseByRecordType

the 1st parameter (both parameters are coming from swagger-ui) is coming as String instead of RecordType

Answer (score -1):

Try below.

```java
@RequestParam(name="recordType") @Schema(allowableValues = {"BILL", "LAW" }) RecordType recordType
```